# Всегда ли не обособляется сочетание "как она есть"?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

Можно написать так:  ***Жизнь, как она есть***.

Допускается обособление устойчивого выражение "как он/она/оно есть" в приведенном предложении, а также в других случаях?

Comment: *Все знают, что сочетание "как она есть" не обособляется* — не знаю и нигде не встречал такого чётко прописанного правила. Полагаю, это проистекает из того, что "как" входит в состав сказуемого. //

 *В картине тонко показана настоящая духовность, как она есть ― без фальши...* — здесь, кажется, просто выпущен повтор слова: *В картине тонко показана настоящая духовность, [духовность] как она есть ― без фальши...* То есть *[духовность] как она есть* и далее — это пояснение, что имеется в виду под *настоящей духовностью*.

Comment: Если не знали, то теперь узнали, что все думают одинаково – не обособляется! Никогда! Почитайте Грамоту ру, наши ответы, ответы на другом форуме, куда я сегодня забрела. Кстати, об этом форуме: люди недалекие,  упертые, невежливые, знания поверхностные или вообще их нет. Ни одной личности! Не бывали там? Меня оттуда выпроводили сразу – не вписалась в коллектив.

Comment: В предложении (про духовность) нет никакого пропуска, просто оборот обособлен. Чем он от других-то отличается? Можно сказать, что это сочетание имеет значение одного слова? Можно, конечно, да только одно слово не так просто обособить, в отличие от распространенного оборота из трех слов. И про сказуемое. Жизнь (есть) как она есть. Смысл сказанного; Жизнь действительная, без идеализации. Вот в таком предложении это именная часть сказуемого. Но вариантов использования оборота много, структура предложений разная. Но ведь и здесь можно поставить ударение: ЖИзнь (такая), как она есть.  Или нельзя?

Comment: 'Такая' требует 'какая', а не 'как'.

Comment: А у меня не требует. Оборот устойчивый, по родам и падежам не изменяется. И почему только одни комментарии, а ответа нет? Вопрос был конкретный: правильно Грамота.ру отвечает или нет? Ваше мнение и его обоснование. пжста.

Comment: Было бы что конкретное ответить, а не размышлизмы, был бы ответ.

Comment: ВСе "размышлизмы" я убрала.  Также постараюсь в дальнейшем не перегружать ими форум.

Comment: Я имел в виду не вопрос, а свои размышления в комментариях)

Comment: Я полагаю, что вы имеели в виду мои размышлизмы, а  также общий подход к постановке вопроса. Вероятно, вопрос должен быть коротким и лаконичным, как и ответ на него. Вполне достаточно двух-трех предложений.

Comment: Я написал: *Было бы что конкретное **ответить***...

Comment: Sharon,  я понял Нектоида однозначно: если бы, кроме его размышлизмов, было что-то конкретное, был бы и ответ. А ответ, как мне кажется, был в начальном варианте вопроса: постановка запятой зависит от структуры предложения и ударений. Вы же сами очень много раз отвечали на подобные спорные случаи как раз в таком ключе. Ну а за вопрос я почти сразу поставил плюс :))

Comment: *'Такая' требует 'какая', а не 'как'.* И у меня, блински нафиг, не требует.

Comment: @Артём Луговой  Артем, а вы о чем? Мне пришлось ваш "блински нафиг" в словаре искать.  Каким синонимим его все-таки можно заменить, а то я ваше настроение никак не пойму.

Comment: @Sharon: это я согласился с вами, что "такая" совсем не обязательно требует "какая". А словцо вставил просто от хорошего настроения без особого смысла. Просто порисоваться. ;) Так мой покойный дядя часто говаривал.

Comment: Ой, можно было и без собачки: ваш же вопрос!

Comment: Здесь не "такая", а "так": *Жизнь [так], как она есть.*

Comment: oleedd, почему вы занимайтесь темами,  которые уже давно обсудили? На форуме  три вопроса, заслуживающих внимания, а отвечать НИКТО не хочет. И мне вы вот не захотели помочь https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471850/Верно-ли-употреблен-деепричастный-оборот
(Впрочем, никто не захотел.)  "Жизнь так".  Где же сказуемое в этом предложении? Можно сказать: Жизнь такова (такая). Ну это я так думаю. а как там в вашей грамматике, трудно догадаться.