# Верно ли употреблен деепричастный оборот?

Tags: согласование, сказуемые, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия, подлежащее

**Будучи** круглым сиротой, ему приходилось много работать.

Comment: На слух фраза кажется некорректной, несмотря на наличие инфинитива в безличном предложении. Остается найти причину.  Правильно: Будучи круглым сиротой, он должен был много работать.

Answer (score 1):

1. Есть мнение, что ошибкой является **наличие местоимение «ему»,** указывающего на производителя  действия.  Тогда правильный вариант: ***Будучи круглым сиротой, приходится/приходилось много работать.***
2. Конечно, Розенталь не говорит об этом, но может это действительно так. Но дело в том, что я **не уверена в правильности** и этого предложения. В Нацкорпусе мне встречались примеры с оборотом "будучи", которые кажутся **верными безо всяких сомнений**, например: ***Будучи ребенком, легко поверить в сказку. Не будучи юристом, трудно разобраться в этом вопросе.***
3. Может быть, этот оборот особенный и здесь нужны дополнительные требования? В чем особенность? Дело в том, что оборот ***будучи кем-то/каким-то*** обозначает не действие как таковое, а **состояние** субъекта действия.

В целом это тема безличных предложений, где к предикативу (слову категории состояния) **тесно примыкает инфинитив**. Кстати, будучи – деепричастие несовершенного вида.

4. И все же мне не нравится исправленный вариант предложения. Нравятся только такие словосочетания: **легко (трудно, невозможно) представить (разобраться, поверить).**

То есть это **потенциальная возможность/невозможность** совершения действия, **будучи** кем-то или каким-то. И всё!

Вот Мережковский:

***Не будучи похожим** на своих читателей, поставить знак равенства между второй всемирной войной и Атлантидой-Европой очень легко; но, **будучи на них похожим**, — очень трудно, почти невозможно.*

Это предложение мне нравится.

5. Здесь **нужна ваша помощь**, уважаемые участники форума. Как редактировать предложение,чтобы оно было правильным.

Я допускаю такой вариант: ***Будучи круглым сиротой, сложно обходиться** без дополнительного заработка.*

Но может, верно и это предложение: *Будучи круглым сиротой, **приходится/приходилось много работать.***